# Steps for pulling from remote using pygit2

Tags: git, pygit2

While using the pygit2 library a simple repo.fetch() fetches all the diffs.
The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23200789/pulling-and-integrating-remote-changes-with-pygit2) describes the steps viz
 1. `Remote.fetch()`
 2. `Repository.create_reference()` or `Reference.target=`
 3. `Repository.checkout_head()`

I am not sure about what is happening under the hood in second step and what parameters need to be passed.
`r.repo.create_reference: (self, name, target, force=False)`

> > Create a new reference "name" which points to an object or to another
> >     reference.
> >
> > Based on the type and value of the target parameter, this method tries
> >     to guess whether it is a direct or a symbolic reference.
> >
> > Keyword arguments:
> >
> > force
> >         If True references will be overridden, otherwise (the default) an
> >         exception is raised.
> >
> > Examples::
> >
> > repo.create_reference('refs/heads/foo', repo.head.target)
> >       repo.create_reference('refs/tags/foo', 'refs/heads/master')
> >       repo.create_reference('refs/tags/foo', 'bbb78a9cec580')

What is happening in the second step and what is meant by `Reference.target=`
Where should it point to?
And how does all this use the `Remote.fetch()` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`create_reference` method](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/7e41bd4af3b980f06f5f6ecae6193270e264da96/pygit2/repository.py#L147) changes the target in order for said target to contains (reference) the name.

Here, after a fetch, you would want to set the reference of the local branch (you want to checkout) to the right remote tracking branch (you just fetched):

```
repo.create_reference('refs/remotes/origin/master', 'refs/heads/master')
```

You can look up the file "`refs/heads/master`" in your `.git` folder: it is a simple file with the reference it has to contain in order for that branch to point to (reference) another branch SHA1.

Comment: This makes thing a bit clear.  
So after `create_reference()` my `'refs/heads/master'` will point to `'refs/remotes/origin/master'`. Right?  

After remote.fetch() where are the received objects kept?  
Suppose I want to check the diff bw my remote and index file how would I go about it?

Comment: @avck "After `remote.fetch()` where are the received objects kept?": in "`refs/remotes/xxx`", with `xxx` being the names of the remotes you have declared in your repo (by default '`origin`')

Comment: When do we use `Reference.target=` and which Reference object will be used here?

Comment: @avck to set the target of the reference (https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/master/docs/references.rst): usually a SHA1 or a branch/tag name (https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/7e41bd4af3b980f06f5f6ecae6193270e264da96/src/reference.c#L205-L208): so you can modify an existing reference or create one. In the case of the master branch, since you likely already have master, you would use `Reference.target` instead of `create_reference()`.

Comment: @avck see a lots of examples of '`reference.target`' usage in https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/master/test/test_refs.py

Comment: cool. So after fetch() I can use `'refs/remotes/xxx'` To check the diff bw my remote and index file
Is this the recommended method of checking the diff of remote repo and current repo before pushing?

Comment: @avck yes, but you need to chose a reference within `refs/remotes/xxx`, like `refs/remotes/origin/master` for instance. And once you have examine the diff, you still need to merge the remote tracking branch to your local branch before pushing anything, or your push won't be a fast-forward one.

Comment: I will try this out.
Thanks for giving your time!

Comment: what is the difference between Repository.checkout_head() and Repository.checkout('HEAD'). Documentation mentions that calling Repository.checkout without arguments will take checkout_index as default. After updating reference if i do Repository.checkout('HEAD'), the index stays modified ie the Repository.status() shows a file with changes. While using Repository.checkout_head() clears the index too. Could you explain what is happening here?

Comment: @avck I suspect (not tested) that `checkout_head()` is the same as `git checkout HEAD -- .`, meaning a checkout on the working tree (which will reset the working tree content: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3107870/6309). While `git checkout HEAD` is for checking out the HEAD of the branch (branch, not files): if that branch is *already checked out*, this is a no-op: nothing happens.

Comment: @avck note that a checkout(HEAD) with the  FORCE option (`repo.checkout('HEAD', pygit2.GIT_CHECKOUT_FORCE)`) would *also* reset the working tree: https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2/blob/d2a62c526862ccdb05bea25d4c77dcc36e080f3f/test/test_repository.py#L234-L247

Comment: After I do `Reference.target=remoteReference.target.hex` the commit history is updated. Resetting the working tree will not be a problem then I guess?